# I am trying to make a minecraft plugin with java 8 where if you get killed by an player, you drop your loot but if you get killed by a mob you keep it

Tags: java, minecraft

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvJAz.png)

theres the code, but the problem is that line 14 does not work and i cannot seem to find anyone else done this

Comment: If you are developing bukkit plugins, ask in bukkit forum/spigot forum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, this is a problem with the types: If you are familiar with Java, you should know that `MCEntity` (example of its usage found with [Tabnine](https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/methods/org.bukkit.entity.Player/getKiller)) is not comparable to type `EntityType`.

Therefore, you will have to use a method to get the `Type` of the `MCEntity` (the `Type` I'm referring to in this context is the MC type, e.g., `PLAYER`, not Java-type).

This method, that exists on the `MCEntity`, is [`MCEntity.getType()`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/entity/Entity.html#getType()) that will return to you the MC-`Type` of the Killer. So you need the code:

```java
public void onPlayerDead(PlayerDeathEvent event) {
    Player playerDead = event.getEntity();

    // Now check for the Type of the Killer with the getType()-method
    if (playerDead.getKiller().getType() == EntityType.PLAYER) {
        event.setKeepInventory(false);
    }
}
```

If you have further questions, feel free to ask, but this question is rather hard to answer because you just provided us one image of your code. Please take a look on how to [format code with markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Furthermore, the line in the editor has a red line. That indicates an error in your code. Asking the question, it would be great if you could give us the exact error message that is shown, when you hover over the red line. That helps a lot while debugging (especially other people's) code!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'm going to assume you are making a spigot plugin.

Instead of `playerDead.getKiller()`, instead use `playerDead.getKiller().getType()`.

To avoid simple problems like this, learn how types work in java, and read javadocs.